# Send multiple HTTP headers with single header() call in PHP

Tags: php, http, header

I send the headers for Cache and Content Type for different languages to show the correct characters, but it does not work.

```
header('Cache-control: private; Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can't send multiple headers in one `header()` call. Split it like that:

```
header('Cache-control: private;');
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Generally, when you send headers, you separate them by new lines, but if you try to do this with PHP's `header()` function, you get warning:

> Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected